# Querying according to the newest related object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities with an 1-N relation, like this :

```
table_a
-------
id
name

table_b
------
id
table_a_id
name
status
created_at
```

I'm looking for a way in MySQL and especially with Doctrine ORM to query table_a with a "where" clause on table_b that affect only the last associated table_b record.

Supposing I have the following records :

```
table_a
----------------------------
id    | name
----------------------------
1     | john
2     | mary
3     | chuck

table_b
--------------------------------------------------
id    | table_a_id | name    | status | created_at
--------------------------------------------------
1     | 1          | blue    | 1      | 2000-01-01
2     | 1          | red     | 1      | 2012-12-31
3     | 2          | yellow  | 1      | 2000-01-01
4     | 2          | green   | 0      | 2012-12-31
```

So I want to tell MySQL/Doctrine : 
GIVE ME the table_a records 
WHICH HAVE table_b records
AND status = 1 ON the last related elements (according to the created_at field)

This should only return :

```
table_a
----------------------------
id    | name
----------------------------
1     | john
```

Comment: Is this about MySQL or about Doctrine? In MySQL it is a classic greatest-n-per-group problem (we even have a tag for that here) for which solutions are given on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: I can use native SQL with Doctrine, so the problem is priorly with MYSQL. Thank you for the url, i'm testing this solution.

Comment: I'm not able to write the correct query... can you give me the correct syntax in the context of my previous exemple please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the book [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns), this type of join with the proper indexes can often perform better than a subquery. So, try this method out too:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b1
  ON b1.table_a_id = a.id
  AND b1.status = 1
LEFT JOIN table_b b2
  ON b2.table_a_id = a.id
  AND b2.created_at > b1.created_at
WHERE b2.table_a_id IS NULL
```

If there could be two rows from table_b with status `1` that have the same `table_a_id` and `created_at` date, then you will need `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b1
  ON b1.table_a_id = a.id
  AND b1.status = 1
LEFT JOIN table_b b2
  ON b2.table_a_id = a.id
  AND b2.created_at > b1.created_at
WHERE b2.table_a_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't understrand the last line (WHERE IS NULL), what does it is used for ?

Comment: The query joins `table_b` onto itself, however it makes sure that `b2.created_at > b1.created_at`.  The joined row with highest `created_at` will then have no result from `b2` as it makes that `>` effectively impossible.  In turn this means that `b2.table_a_id` (or anything from `b2`) is NULL.  This means that the applicable row from `b1` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Simonatmso.net and Marcus, it's clear now and works like a charm!

Comment: Two years later, I have a question : what would be the query if I only want the records from table_a where b1.status = 1, but witch ARE NOT the most recent (any table_b is matching, but not the one with the highest created_at?

Comment: I'm thinking just change the WHERE clause to `WHERE b2.table_a_id IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the "Doctrine", but a MySQL query could be

```
select
      a.ID,
      a.Name
   from
      table_b B
         join table_a A
            on B.table_a_id = A.ID
   where
      B.status = 1
   order by
      B.Created_At DESC
   limit 1
```

Comment: I dont' want to limit the results of the query. Your query will always return only one table_a record. The limitation must only concerns the relation.